# Why is the timestamp wrong using Winlogbeat?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I successfully obtained the logs of another Ubuntu server with filebeat. I installed winlogbeat on Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit. At first, the two machines worked well, but after ten minutes I couldn't see Windows logs.

I shutdown the other Ubuntu server and checked winlogbeat logs and I realized that the time of the publish event on winlogbeat didn't match with the timestamp field.

I can receive the logs but I have to change the kibana timer to "Last 2 hours".

Winlogbeat log:

```
2016-11-08T16:36:54+01:00 DBG  Publish: {
  "@timestamp": "2016-11-08T15:36:52.492Z",
  "beat": {
    "hostname": "Admin-PC",
    "name": "Admin-PC",
    "version": "5.0.0"
  },
  "computer_name": "Admin-PC",
  "event_data": {
    "PrivilegeList": "SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege\n\t\t\tSeTcbPrivilege\n\t\t\tSeSecurityPrivilege\n\t\t\tSeTakeOwnershipPrivilege\n\t\t\tSeLoadDriverPrivilege\n\t\t\tSeBackupPrivilege\n\t\t\tSeRestorePrivilege\n\t\t\tSeDebugPrivilege\n\t\t\tSeAuditPrivilege\n\t\t\tSeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege\n\t\t\tSeImpersonatePrivilege",
    "SubjectDomainName": "NT AUTHORITY",
    "SubjectLogonId": "0x3e7",
    "SubjectUserName": "SYSTEM",
    "SubjectUserSid": "S-1-5-18"
  },
  "event_id": 4672,
  "keywords": [
    "Auditoría correcta"
  ],
  "level": "Información",
  "log_name": "Security",
  "message": "Se asignaron privilegios especiales a un nuevo inicio de sesión.\n\nSujeto:\n\tId. de seguridad:\t\tS-1-5-18\n\tNombre de cuenta:\t\tSYSTEM\n\tDominio de cuenta:\t\tNT AUTHORITY\n\tId. de inicio de sesión:\t\t0x3e7\n\nPrivilegios:\t\tSeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege\n\t\t\tSeTcbPrivilege\n\t\t\tSeSecurityPrivilege\n\t\t\tSeTakeOwnershipPrivilege\n\t\t\tSeLoadDriverPrivilege\n\t\t\tSeBackupPrivilege\n\t\t\tSeRestorePrivilege\n\t\t\tSeDebugPrivilege\n\t\t\tSeAuditPrivilege\n\t\t\tSeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege\n\t\t\tSeImpersonatePrivilege",
  "opcode": "Información",
  "process_id": 480,
  "provider_guid": "{54849625-5478-4994-A5BA-3E3B0328C30D}",
  "record_number": "611",
  "source_name": "Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing",
  "task": "Inicio de sesión especial",
  "thread_id": 528,
  "type": "wineventlog"
}
```

---

I've ELK on Ubuntu (Logstash v2.3.4, ElasticSearch v1.7.3, and Kibana v4.1.2).

Comment: Are you shipping to logstash or straight to elasticsearch?

Comment: I've tried both with the same result. I think the problem comes directly from winlogbeat.

Comment: Are you using logstash's date{} filter to update the @timestamp field?  That will make events "move"...